# Pentaho Aggregation Designer: Are the aggregation names generated usable

Tags: designer, aggregation, pentaho

I have used the aggregation designer to generate some tables. I just wanted to know is there anything else I have to modify in the cube definition xml? Currently it look likes the aggname name attribute values generated wont match correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The aggregates generated worked unmodified